# print double quotes inside a parentheses in vba?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

i want to write below line in different way:

```
Shell ("myapp.exe")
```

i have tried but its not working as i expected: 
it is working this way:

```
Dim var1
var1 = """m" & "y" & "app" & "." & "exe"""
Shell (var1)
```

but not this way

```
Dim var1
var1 = """m" & "y" & "app" & "." & "exe"""
Dim var2
Set var2 = Shell(var1)

var2
```

its not as working as same. what i am doing wrong.

how to correct this?

Comment: What do you mean by different way ?

Comment: `var1 = """myapp.exe"""` ?

Comment: What is var2 supposed to do, get data from the myapp.exe shell session?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Chr(34)` function to return the `"` character, such as in the line below:

```
Dim var1
var1 = Chr(34) & "m" & "y" & "app" & "." & "exe" & Chr(34)
```

Or, the shorter version:

```
var1 = Chr(34) & "myapp.exe" & Chr(34)
```

The `Chr()` function can be used with any ASCII value you may need. you can find other ASCII values [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php).

Comment: `Chr()` uses ANSI character codes, which vary from machine to machine, user to user and time to time. VBA uses Unicode (UTF-16) for strings so `ChrW()` is almost always the correct function for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid putting the quotes in your variable name. While `Shell` does allow a quoted string, if you want the same result as your initial command (that doesn't have them), you shouldn't put them in.

```
var1 = "m" & "y" & "app" & "." & "exe"
```